# Origen, significado y uso actual de "marta"

Tags: etimología, historia

Según el DLE, se da un origen y 2 acepciones a la palabra [marta<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OUnlCMF).

> De *Marta*, hermana de María y Lázaro, quien, según los Evangelios, cuando Jesús se hospedó en su casa, preparaba solícitamente la comida, mientras su hermana María conversaba con Jesús.
>
> 1. f. Mujer piadosa y a la vez atenta al trabajo de casa.
>
> 2. f. Mujer aprovechada.

Sin embargo, el origen se acopla más al primer significado que al segundo.

¿De dónde surge ese segundo significado? ¿Qué tan usado es en la actualidad en el mundo hispano? (Hoy fue la primera vez que leí ese significado en un diccionario.)

Comment: la marta tambien es una especie de mamifero

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la explicación a esa segunda acepción de marta = mujer aprovechada es que el *aprovechada* hace referencia a la primera o a la segunda acepción de [aprovechado, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3KDBlir) y no a la tercera:

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que saca provecho de todo, y más aún, que utiliza lo que otros suelen desperdiciar o despreciar.
> 2. adj. Aplicado, diligente.
> 3. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que saca beneficio de las circunstancias que se le presentan favorables, normalmente sin escrúpulos. U. t. c. s.

Si es así, no hay una gran contraposición entre las dos acepciones de [marta<sup>1</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OUnlCMF).

Comment: Alicia, para darte la repuesta, hace falta la última pregunta del uso actual de ese significado en la actualidad, en que zonas se tiende a realizar o hasta cuando se solía usar (aunque prácticamente es un significado similar al primero), pues no he oído o leído el caso de 'Esa señora es una marta' con ese significado (en Colombia, suroccidente para más señas)

Answer (score 2):

**TL; DR:** Ni la RAE sabe a qué acepción de *aprovechada* se refiere la definición de *marta*.

Hace ya cinco días pregunté a la RAE a través de Enclave a qué se refiere el diccionario cuando dice que *marta* es una "mujer aprovechada". Se han tomado su tiempo pero por fin han respondido, y la respuesta desde luego no deja de ser curiosa.

> En efecto, tal como usted sugiere, faltaría una glosa en la segunda acepción del artículo **marta<sup>1</sup>**. En principio, con la documentación con la que contamos, es difícil determinar cuál es el referente de la expresión *mujer aprovechada*. Cabría interpretar que, a partir de la primera acepción de esta voz —directamente relacionada con el carácter que se atribuye en los Evangelios a la hermana de Lázaro con este nombre—, su significado se desliza hacia un sentido más general de mujer que saca provecho de todo, que es aplicada, diligente y ahorradora en el cuidado de su casa. No obstante, si tenemos en cuenta la redacción anterior de este artículo (en las ediciones del DRAE entre 1869 y 1970, y a la que puede acceder a través del *Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española*), cabría postular una acepción peyorativa, relacionada con la que aparecía entonces (*Marta la piadosa*, 'mujer gazmoña e hipócrita').
>
> En todo caso, trasladamos este caso al Instituto de Lexicografía, a fin de que se realice un estudio que posibilite la adscripción del adjetivo *aprovechado* a uno de los tres sentidos que para este término recoge el propio *DLE*.

La entrada a la que se refiere la RAE es la que relacionaba el uso de la expresión *Marta la piadosa* con el significado de "mujer gazmoña e hipócrita", basada en un refrán antiguo: "Marta la piadosa, que mascaba la miel a los enfermos".

Comment: ¿Sabes acaso en donde se use la palabra con ese significado? (Ya sea país, región, época u obra literaria)